# Autodesk Forge + design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I need some help with building a component that can take two dwg files as an input and produce one output file, in other words combine two files. my plan is to use web service to send and receive files.  Is this possible? if yes then how?

Comment: Hi, as Albert mentioned, you can do anything with design automation like what you did in local AutoCAD. Even you could run your plugin on design automation. With my understanding on your requirement, you would need to produce a plugin which reads the drawings list (can be a file that indicates the url of the drawings), merges them and produces an output. design automation supports embed parameter or linked parameter. OR you could provide an zip with all drawings for design automation, then your plugin unzip the file and merge them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

what does "combining" mean in this context? Can you describe this in terms of AutoCAD commands/features? Design Automation can do pretty much everything that AutoCAD can do.
For example:
Use INSERT command to add one drawing into the other (then you need to know where to insert it, what scale to use)